# sql trigger is not working when data is pushed from postman

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

When I'm trying to delete the data by Trigger it is deleting the data for full table - not only the Where clause one.

```
Create TRIGGER trgAfterInsertFDs ON [dbo].MyTable
FOR INSERT,Delete
AS
    declare @id nvarchar(max)
    declare @Status nvarchar(100);

    select @id=i.ID from inserted i;    
    select @Status=i.[Status] from inserted i;  
    Delete from MyTable where ID=@id and [Status]='Closed'
GO
```

I have tried Other Way as well. To dump the Auto generated ID from My Table to Another Table and wrote one more trigger to delete the data from My Table.

```
Create TRIGGER trgAfterInsert ON [dbo].MyTable
FOR INSERT,Delete
AS
    declare @id nvarchar(max)
    declare @Status nvarchar(100);

    select @id=i.ID from inserted i;    
    select @Status=i.[Status] from inserted i;  
    Delete from MyTable where ID=@id and [Status]='Closed'
        Insert into ClosedID
    Select ID,[Status] from [dbo].MyTable where ID=@id and Status='Closed'
GO
```

table ClosedID:

```
Create table ClosedID 
  (ID int,Status nvarchar(max))


Create TRIGGER trgAfter ON ClosedID
FOR INSERT
AS
    declare @ID nvarchar(max)
    declare @Status nvarchar(100);

    select @id=i.ID from inserted i;    
    select @Status=i.Status from inserted i;    
    delete from [dbo].MyTable where id in (Select ID from ClosedID)
    --Delete  from ClosedID
GO
```

Comment: `select @id=i.ID from inserted i;` you are assuming there will only be one record in `inserted`. The inserted pseudo table can hold 0, 1 or more than 1 record(s).

Comment: `trgAfterInsertFDs ` is an AFTER trigger - delete operation has already happened and  inside this trigger you are trying to _double_ delete _some_ of those (already deleted) records.

Comment: Why are you also trying to `DELETE` rows and then `INSERT` The details of those rows into a history table afterwards?  If you've deleted them first, then you `INSERT` statement is going to have 0 rows to process. I think we need to better understand what it is your actually trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 0):

In your first trigger you don't need to trigger on DELETE for your purpose. Because you want to delete for specific condition but if it is already deleted you don't need to trigger it to delete.
And you should consider bulk inserts, your trigger should cover it. I have simplified your first trigger. 
By the way normally if I want to ignore some insert records on the table I prefer **INSTEAD OF INSERT** Trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgAfterInsertFDs ON [dbo].MyTable
FOR INSERT
AS
    DELETE FROM MyTable 
        WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INSERTED I WHERE MyTable.Id=I.Id AND I.[Status]='Closed')
GO
```